# How to open Keyboard programmatically when move from one activity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i am trying to open keyboard when i move to first activity to second activity. 
There is two button in main activity 
1) if click on "NotShowKeyboard" button it will open the second.java activity with out keyboard 
2) if s"ShowKeyboard" button is clicked then it will open the second.java activity with keyboard and EitdText with focus
 But problem is that i don't know how to do that. I put some examples top show keyboard but on "ShowKeyboard" button click keyboard open and immediately disappear.

Main.java:

```
    NotShowKeyboard.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                bundle.putBoolean("show", false);
                Intent start = new Intent(Main.this, Start.class);
                start.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(start);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    ShowKeyboard.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                bundle.putBoolean("show", true);
                Intent start = new Intent(Main.this, Start.class);
                start.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(start);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Second.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    i = getIntent();
    extras = i.getExtras();
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start_edit);
    search.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
    if((extras.getBoolean("show"))==true) {
    ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    //getting all stuff like buttons imageViews etc.. 
}
```

When NotShowButton Clicked then this should open:

[image]

When ShowButton Clicked then this should open:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Try and put this code in `onResume()`

Comment: If it is only worked after 10 tries, then it is not a solution ;)

Answer (score 12):

For hiding keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

For Showing keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: I find the behaviour of InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT more desirable. I closes the keyboard when you press the home button for example.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on the device, if the softkeyboard comes up or not. On my Vodafone Smart II phone there didnt came it (3,5" display) on my Intexo TAB814 (8" display) there it was. Same App, but different results. It also semms to depend on the android version u use. (Vodafone smart II -> 2.1.3, Intenso tablet 4.1) try on another device

Comment: at that time i haven't any problem with the device. issue is that keyboard is showing but for 1 second and disappear immediately.

Comment: 'if((extras.getBoolean("show"))==true)
    {

         ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }' is your keyboard=true button, ya? then try using 'SHOW_IMPLICIT' instead of 'HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY'